# Platform independent way of restarting Equinox container?

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I currently have an application using an Equinox OSGI container that runs on both Windows and Linux. Each platform has there own startup scripts. As part of updating sometimes the container has  to be restarted. Is there a way from with  in JAVA code to restart an Equinox OSGI container with out calling out to a platform specific script?

Comment: I think restarting the bundle with ID 0 does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just launch the framework using the `FrameworkFactory` API.

When your launcher program has done all of the setup it wants, it should call `framework.waitForStop()`, which blocks until OSGi shuts down. This method also returns a `FrameworkEvent` that you can look at. If the event type is `STOPPED_UPDATE` then you should loop back and boot the framework again.